# Summon flying ender_pearl

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

### We know:

If a player uses `/summon minecraft:ender_pearl`
It summons a ender pearl that falls from the player coordinates to the ground (best way to see: fly in creative mod)e.

---

How do I let the pearl fly in a arc like a player threw it?

---

Would be nice if you can tell me if it works fore: arrows and other things like that ⁠•⁠‿⁠•

---

Minecraft, Java-Edition, Vanilla-1.20

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Do you want to summon an ender pearl with the same trajectory as if a player threw it? Do you want to summon an ender pearl when a player shoots a bow with the trajectory of the arrow?

Comment: @LostXOR I mean: how to Summon a ender pearl that flies in a specific direction in an arc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summon an ender pearl that flies in an arc, use the `Motion` NBT tag.

```
/summon ender_pearl ~ ~ ~ {Motion:[<x>,<y>,<z>]}
```

`x`, `y`, and `z` are the pearl's speed in the X, Y, and Z directions, in blocks per tick.

For example, to summon an ender pearl moving at 2 blocks per tick in the -X direction (west) and 0.5 blocks per tick in the Y direction (upwards).

```
/summon ender_pearl ~ ~ ~ {Motion:[-2.0,0.5,0.0]}
```

The pearl will arc upwards and to the west.